# Defining state and action for Q-learning in the code

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I am trying to understand the following code for the simulator to avoid collision with the help of Q-learning. The examples and tutorials which I followed had the space divided into blocks such as taxiv3, so it was rather easier to define state and action spaces. But in this code, the simulator produces random sectors and I am trying to figure out a way to define the state space and action space.

Please let me know if you need more information on my question if it is too vague.

https://github.com/ramondalmau/atcenv/blob/main/atcenv/env.py